# Convergence on interval vs on R

Tags: convergence-divergence

If $f_n$ -> f uniformly on every finite interval [a,b], does this imply it converges uniformly on R?

I would think yes, since R can be expressed as a sum of intervals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the Taylor series for $e^x$ around $x=0$.